# How to fix Calendar after using setTimeZone?

Tags: java, timestamp

The following code produces unecpected behaviour:
I am expecting both `Calendar` returning same value for `getTimeInMillis` at the end (`1469008800000` in this case) and they shall be `equal`. - but they don't do...

I think this has somethig to do with http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4827490 but calling `get` after `setTimeZone` does'nt change anything as posted as "WORK AROUND" ("after changing the time zone, we must call some read method")...

Or is the "WORK AROUND" wrong and one has to call some `get` method **before** using `setTimeZone`?

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
calendar1.set(2016, 07 - 1, 20, 12, 00, 0);
calendar2.set(2016, 07 - 1, 20, 12, 00, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
calendar2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println("creation: " + calendar1.equals(calendar2));

System.out.println(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println("get: " + calendar1.equals(calendar2));

calendar1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Z"));
calendar2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Z"));

System.out.println("setTimeZone: " + calendar1.equals(calendar2));

calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);

System.out.println("get: " + calendar1.equals(calendar2));

System.out.println();
System.out.println(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(calendar2.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("end: " + calendar1.equals(calendar2));
```

output:

```
creation: true
1469008800000
get: true
setTimeZone: false
get: false

1469008800000
1469016000000
end: false
```

Answer (score 0):

May I point out that in the code you provide,  you set both calendars to the exact same expression, but the `Calendar.MILISECONDS` changes value from one call to the other scince time passes between the two calls.

You should be allright if you set the second calendar to the first one, instead of setting it to the `Calendar.MILISECONDS`.

EDIT: After the question got edited, my answer is no longer relevant, I am keeping it for the sole purpose of keeping its comment section.

Comment: Did you see the difference between those values? 7200000ms so exaclty 2 hours.

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize, at this point my answer is not in topic, but it will stand that even without a bug of any kind, the two values could not be equal, just the differences should be much smaller.

Comment: @André you verified it after line 6 with the System.out from the last line, and it gave true?

Comment: @eldo: Yes, the 2h are the difference between CET and Z - but timestamp should be equal...

Comment: @CMax: I updated the code: After using setTimeZone the Calendars are not equal anymore...

Comment: @André: I see, sorry for the off topic answer then, but this way your question is much clearer, it probably is a bug of some kind... Have you tried to set the timezone of calendar2 to the one of calendar1 instead of a new one?

Comment: `calendar2.setTimeZone(calendar1.getTimeZone());` instead of `calendar2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Z"));` produces same result...